# Suma de Riemann no devuelve el valor esperado

Tags: java

Escribí este código para hallar la suma de Riemann dada una función, un intervalo y precisión que sería n, pero cuando lo ejecuto me devuelve "2.0E -8", y pues en mi calculadora esta es 6.6666666666666

¿Podrían por favor ayudarme a ver qué está mal?

```
class Suma{
  public static void main (String[]args){

    double x=0;
    double y=Math.pow(x,2)+x+1 ;//función en x
    double a=0;//cota inferior
    double b=2;//cota superior
    double n=100000000;
    double delta=(b-a)/n;//variación de x
    double S=0;//suma
    for(int i=1;i<n+1;i++){
    x=a+i*delta;
    S=+y;   
    }
    S=S*delta;
    System.out.println(S);
    //Scanner i =new Scanner(System.in);
    //n=i.nextInt();

  }
}
```

Comment: Podrias explicar de forma detallada la formula que estas aplicando?

Comment: No veo donde guardas la operación de X ( x=a+i*delta; ) no es lo mismo s+=y (suma) que s=+y (vuelve el valor en positivo y sobre escribe el valor actual por el nuevo).

Comment: @Crack81, pues va así, primero declaro la variable independiente "x" ,le asigné un valor porque java requiere que la inicie, luego sigue la varaible dependiente de "x" que es "y", la expresión que contiene es de mera prueba.

Comment: @Crack81 Luego está, desde donde hasta que lugar va la suma, que serían "b" y "a". La variable "n" es la cantidad de intervalos que se va a utilizar entre mayor sea, mejor; y delta sería la distancia que hay entre cada intervalo, ah! y S sería el valor de la suma. Luego en el bucle "for" "x" tiene que variar su valor para que "y" cambie en cada repetición,luego la Sn=Sn-1 + y.

Comment: @Crack81 y por último una vez que termine el bucle, como es posible factorizar la suma de Riemann, solo haria falta multiplicar "S" por "delta".

Comment: @JoseLuis La "x" se guarda en "y", y como "x" varía "y" también lo hace , pero ¿Podrías explicar que S+=y es diferente de S=+y?.

Comment: @Brocolio no veo que hagas una asignación, haces primero [x = a + i * delta;] y no haces después [y+=x] después ya la parte [S+=y] o como sea el seguimiento de tu operación. La parte < S=+Y > primero vuelve el valor en positivo, por ejemplo S = +1 (afecta tus operaciones), en la siguiente iteración haría: S=+2, y el valor anterior (+1) sería reemplazado por el nuevo número, la sintaxis S+=y; es lo mismo que hacer s = s + y; lo cual suma, y en cadenas concatena.

Comment: @JoseLuis, ¿Es necesario "[y+=x]"? la variable "y" depende "x", si esta cambia ¿no cambiará "y" también?

Comment: @JoseLuis cambié el S=+y por S=S+y para evitar confusiones, y pues resulta que ya no me retorna E-9, sólo lo el 2.0, lo cuál es erróneo de todas formas.

Answer (score 0):

intenta con esto

```
BigDecimal big = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(S));
    System.out.println(big.toPlainString());
```

Comment: Hola que tiene que ver tu solucion con el problema?

Comment: Una pregunta ¿si resultado es un periódico puro, no habrá errores al momento de almacenarlo?